# Python x[1:2:3] in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

Right to the point:
I'm trying to find some JavaScript version of the Python list split function
ex:

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x[1:4]
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Array.slice() :

```
var x=[1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(x.slice(1,4)); // => [2, 3, 4]
```

However, Python's slicing includes a step, which means slice an element then move to element with index+STEP, and this is it in JavaScript :

```
Array.prototype.mySlice = function(b,e,s) {
    var n=[];
    for (var i=b; i<e; i+=s) {
        n.push(this[i]);
    }
    return n;
}
var x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
console.log(x.mySlice(1,7,2)); // => [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I'm new to the JavaScript scene and this will help me greatly. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

That would be `slice`:

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(a.slice(1, 4))
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using `array slicing`.

Snippet:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
console.log(fruits.slice(1, 3));
```

More information and source: [JavaScript Array slice() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use block scope, destructuring assignment, trailing comma

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
{
  [, a, b, c, ] = x;
  x = [a, b, c];
};
console.log(x);
```

Comment: That will only work if you know the exact length of the input array.

Comment: @thepieterdc Not sure what you mean?

Comment: the poster of the question probably requires a generic answer that will work with any start/end bound. Your example would only work for a hardcoded start/end (1/3 respectively in this example).

Comment: @thepieterdc Any index can be destructured from input array. Substituting object destructing for trailing comma `({1:a, 2:b, 3:c} = x); x = [a, b, c];`